# Run script in terminal after boot

Tags: raspbian

I added the following to `/etc/rc.local`

```
(
    cd /home/pi/Desktop
    exec ./start_picoin.sh
) &
```

The script it executes is nothing more then a simple echo at the moment.
I would like this script to be executed in a terminal that stays open after execution.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a very nice tool called **[tmux](https://tmux.github.io/)**. I use it everyday and what it basically does is gives the end user to run multiple scripts in *detached* mode (background), however a user can log in to the *Detached Session* whenever s/he wants at any given time.

- You can install it via:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install tmux
  ```
- In your case you could write a the tmux trigger on boot into your `rc.local` file as follows:

  ```
  ## YOUR rc.local file
  #!/bin/sh -e

  # always good and safe to use the complete path
  /usr/bin/tmux new-session -d -s mySession

  # This statement is a life-saver, if ever your code crashes
  /usr/bin/tmux set-option -t mySession set-remain-on-exit on

  # Create a window where you wish to run a code
  /usr/bin/tmux new-window -d -n 'my work' -t mySession:1 'cd /home/pi/Desktop; exec ./start_picoin.sh'

   exit 0
  ```
- Now since your `/etc/rc.local` file is triggered on boot under `sudo` rights, the next time you boot you can see your session `mySession` by typing:

  ```
  sudo tmux ls
  ```
- Once you see the session has begun, all you have to do is attach the background session using:

  ```
  sudo tmux a
  ```
- You will see an empty bash shell, in order to navigate to your running code press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
- Once you see your code running well and want to leave the code running in the background you can simply click: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to detach it.
- If you want to close the complete session you can just type:

  ```
  sudo tmux kill-session
  ```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/auto-running-programs-gui

I am assuming you are using GUI rather than command line? Follow that guide above to launch lxterminal on start up. If you have a script called *BootScript.sh* in the */home/pi* directory then in your autostart file you want to add:

```
@lxterminal -e "/home/pi/BootScript.sh"
```

your script will read something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello World!

$SHELL
```

The $SHELL part at the ends stops the terminal screen from closing. Make sure you give your script execution privileges using:

```
chmod -755 /home/pi/BootScript.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not simple because Raspbian will not give you terminal on boot logged in by default.

First, you need to edit `/etc/inittab` to enable auto login in your preferred console.

Then I would suggest to add your script to `~/.bashrc` and it will execute on login.

**EDIT**

I've just realized that you asked something else:

Answer is to use `nohup` before your call.

So, it would be `nohup myscript.sh &` and it will run after you logout.